# When updating resources in bulk and one of them errors out should the rest be updated?

Tags: rest

I need to updated resources in bulk like

```js
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Ben',
},
{ id: 2, name: 'John' }];
```

If the first entity errors out, should the second be updated or an error returned by the REST principles?